# Anyone know what the purpose of tagging a class with *[class]

Tags: css, mobile, html-email

I received a file from a client today that is a template for an e-mail and in the css for the mobile version all of the class specifications were preceded with *[class]

e.g.

```
*[class].centertext {
somespec:0;
}
```

anyone know what the purpose of adding that to a class is?

thanks.

Comment: Ask the original author?  If it isn't to increase the specificity of the selector, it is probably a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [yahoo fix/bug workaround](http://www.emailonacid.com/blog/details/C13/stop_yahoo_mail_from_rendering_your_media_queries) that uses this technique (css classes) in html email design. There was a bug where Yahoo rendered all media queries by default, and this was the common solution.

There have been reports that Yahoo fixed the bug recently.

Answer (score 0):

The square brackets are attribute selectors and the '*' is a wild card, so your client is selecting every element that has the class attribute.

Comment: Is there any reason to think that this would increase performance over just a `.centertext` entry?

Comment: not sure what the purpose of it is, but it is being used as part of a responsive layout:@media all and (max-width: 580px){*[class].paddingl0{ padding-left:0px !important;}
  *[class].paddingl5{ padding-left:5px !important;}
  *[class].paddingr5{ padding-right:5px !important;}
  *[class].paddingr0{ padding-right:0px !important;}
  *[class].paddingr10{ padding-right:10px !important;} }

Comment: The [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18878968/1857107) provided by John seems to be correct, it is a work around for the way yahoo mail renders media queries.